# How to remove case sensitive folder from Mercurial repo?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

In BitBucket Mercurial repo, I have two folders: converter and Converter.

But when I clone the repo, I have only Converter folder that has content of both (MacOS).

I want to remove Converter folder. How can I do it?

Comment: You may need to go to a case-sensitive OS/file system to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it on a system that respects case (and you can turn your mac into one next time you format the disk), but there are also tricks to get around it:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions